# How to safely stop a message listener

Tags: jms, tibco-ems

If I have a JMS message listener that processes messages from a queue, how do I stop the listener safely from the main thread?

In the listener onMessage() method, I need to call the Message.acknowledgement() to delete the message from the queue:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    logger.info("Message received " + message.getJMSMessageID());
    // do something.
    message.acknowledge();
}
```

In the main thread, I don't think I can simply just call connection.close() without knowing whether a thread is currently in the middle of onMessage().

Is the alternate synchronous receive() method a better solution since it's single thread and I have better control?

Comment: Calling connection.stop from main thread will stop delivery of messages to a message listener. If you are using a "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"d session, then you can call message.acknowledge() in onMessage. That will delete the message from the queue.

Comment: If connection.stop() is called before message.acknowledge(), then would it not cause the latter to fail?

Comment: No, it will not. JMS implementations would ensure the current onMessage call is completed before stopping message delivery.

Comment: When Connection.stop() is called, does it block until onMessage() is completed? I'm asking this because I am not sure if I can safely call Connection.close() after Connection.stop(). If Connection.stop() waits until onMessage() is completed, then calling Connection.close() after that would be fine.

Comment: OK I've read the JMS API spec. Calling Connection.stop() will block until onMessage() is returned.